# En android Studio, declarar varias Clases desde inicio de aplicación en manifest

Tags: android, class, android-manifest

Requiero tener variables globlales por lo tanto cree la Clase "ClassGlobal" donde tendré mis variables, sin embargo anteriormente se me presento el error MultiDex por lo tanto cree la clase "YourApplication", y mi manifest inicia con esta clase; por lo que veo en guias mi Clase "ClassGlobal" deberia iniciar con la applicacion, ¿como le hago para tener ambas clases desde un inicio?

NOTA: empece a programar desde CERO en Enero2020.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda siempre agregar el codigo como texto ya que de esta forma es visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad, revisa [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento bàsico del sitio,saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En cuanto a la clase "ClassGlobal" donde deseas definir tus variables no podràs extender de `Application` ya que tienes una clase que extiende de `MultidexApplication` y esta clase ya extiende de `Application`.**

Una opciòn es definir simplemente tu clase `ClassGlobal` sin extender de `Application`:

```
public class ClassGlobal {

    public static final String PREFS_CONFIG = "Preferences_Config";
    public static final String PREFS_A = "Android_System";
    public static final int CONTADOR = 0;
    ...
    ...

}
```

---

Para habilitar el modo multidex lo puedes realizar desde tu archivo `build.gradle` definiendo  `multiDexEnabled true` dentro del bloque `defaultConfig` :

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a ver... en tu pregunta hay que aclarar varios conceptos.... ,

el manifest.xml no sirve para indicar las clases que tendra el proyecto, este archivo sirve para proporcionar determinada informacion sobre tu aplicacion, como por ejemplo los permisos se necesitaran, el hardware, etc.... pero sobretodo este archivo se utiliza para indicar que activitys( y como se lllaman) tiene tu proyecto, no lo confundas con clases.... las activitys en android , son "las ventanas" o "pantallas".

estas activitys se declaran como una clase normal, pero que extienden de superclases estandares como "Appcompat", por lo tanto en el archivo manifest tu le estas indicando que activitys tiene tu proyecto y que activity sera la que se ejecutara al principio cuando arranque tu aplicacion

por lo tanto si tu tienes una clase donde agrupas las variables globales a modo de "indice", es decir , multidex, esto tiene ciertas limitaciones aqui te dejo  el link donde habla sobre el mutidex en android , y las limitaciones....

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es

Comment: En este caso si puede declara en el Manifest una clase que extiende de MultidexApplication, esta clase sirve para inicializar singletons de procesos que se encontraran atados a la aplicación.

Comment: gracias por el aviso, pero a mi siempre me habia dado problemas cuando quiero crear constantes globales para toda la aplicacion, como la tipica constante de tamaño letra, o tamaño iconos etc,